# If I upgrade Ubuntu am I in danger of messing up XP installed on the same PC?

Tags: dual-boot, 10.04, firefox

Worked fine last week. Firefox now greys out and I can't click on any menu items. Have been applying updates as they appear but have just learnt elsewhere on this site that that's a waste of time and I should upgrade to latest Ubuntu version. I'm running Ubuntu and Windows XP on same PC (Mozilla is OK in Windows). If I upgrade Ubuntu am I in danger of messing up XP?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: upgrade to windows 7 xp too easy to hack now

Answer (score 0):

No, an upgrade will not (and can not) change anything outside its own partition. So go ahead. You have two options: upgrade to 12.04 and then to 14.04; or back up your data and do a fresh install of 14.04. I would prefer the latter.